# SideNav opening the page in the same window (Yii2)

Tags: yii2, navbar

I am trying to use SideNav URL open the page in the same window not redirecting to the different place. How can i do this ? when someone click the link in the sidenav page should be open in the same window.

```
<?= SideNav::widget([
            'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
            'heading' => 'Dashboard',
            'items' => [
                [
                    'url' => '#',
                    'label' => 'Purchase',
                    'icon' => 'home',
                     'items' => [
                         ['label' => 'Suppliers', 'icon'=>'glyphicon transport', 'url'=>'../site/about'],
                         ['label' => 'Leaf Entry', 'icon'=>'leaf', 'url'=>'#'],
                         ['label' => 'Payments', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
                         ['label' => 'Reports', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#']
                        ],
                ],
```

above code about page open as a different window. i need to open in the same window. how can i do this friends ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your link items add a class for example `ajaxLoad` , then add the following js code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLoad', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#main-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
});
```

lets assume you want your page content to be rendered inside a container div which has a id of **main-content**

the idea is, js script will listen for click events and when someone click on a link that has **ajaxLoad** class, it will grab the `href` value of it and load that pages content inside the `main-content` div.

**note** that in your controller action you have to use **`renderAjax`** instead of `render`.